# Prohibit user from issuing a specific sudo command

Tags: linux, sudo, rvm

I'm using the Ruby Version Manager (RVM) which strongly recommends to never run the rvm command on linux prefaced by 'sudo'. How can I allow myself to run the command without sudo as I am supposed to, but either prohibit or warn before prefacing it with 'sudo'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the file `/etc/sudoers` change the `%wheel` entry:

`%wheel ALL=ALL,!/usr/bin/rvm`

using the correct absolute path for rvm.  This will allow members of the wheel group to use `sudo` with any command *except* `rvm`

attempting to do so will give you a message:

`Sorry, user *username* is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/rvm' as root on *hostname*.`

Edit: on my system, the sudo group is "wheel", but you could specify any group to have specific sudo privileges.

Comment: So, I think I have succeeded, but by substituting %wheel with %sudo, the %sudo group being, I presume, the one that needs to be addressed for anyone wanting to use the sudo command?

Comment: On most Linux systems, the group that allows one to use `sudo` is named `wheel`.